# Spectral theorem for unbounded operators

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, unbounded-operators

Part of the Spectral theorem for unbounded operators states that if $A$ is a self adjoint unbounded operator and $B$ is a bounded operator such that $BA$ is contained in $AB$, then $B$ commutes with all of the spectral projections of $A$. However, every proof I have seen of this seems to depend on the particular construction of the spectral resolution of $A$.

My question is:  can the above statement formally be derived merely from the existence of the spectral resolution of $A$? I note that this is the case when $A$ is bounded.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your assumption is equivalent to saying $(A-\lambda_0)^{-1}B=B(A-\lambda_0)^{-1}$ for $\lambda_0$ in the resolvent set of $A$ or $f(A)B=Bf(A)$ if $f(t)=(t-\lambda_0)^{-1}$. Taking $\lambda_0=x\pm i\lambda$ and subtracting, the same holds for $f(t)=\lambda ((t-x)^2+\lambda^2)^{-1}$. Since linear combinations of these functions approximate (in the sup-norm) continuous functions with compact support, the same holds for these last and, again by approximation, for characteristic functions of intervals...and then of Borel sets.

Comment: I did not check all the details, but this is a way to prove the uniqueness of the functional calculus which seems to extend to the case.

Comment: Thanks @Giorgio. Might you be aware of a reference for this argument in the literature?

Comment: This is really a point. I had a look at my old notes and I found the argument I wrote above, but I am unable to remember where it is taken from. It seeems not to be contained in Reed-Simon 1, nor Davies, nor Kreyszig. I am sorry, I can give more details if you need but not a reference.